# Why is my transitionend event triggering immideately?

Tags: jquery, css, events, jquery-mobile, css-transitions

I'm trying to create a transition between two elements by adding and removing classes to both elements. I'm using the transitions and classes provided by jQuery Mobile.

I got it to work using a `setTimeout` but this is not the way it's supposed to work.

Here is what I'm currently doing:

```
_transitionEndEvents : "webkitTransitionEnd oTransitionEnd otransitionend transitionend msTransitionEnd"

// triggered by a radio button being changed
_onChange: function (e) {
    var self = this,
      el = self.element,
      o = self.options,
      activeElement = el.children().filter(".ui-carousel-active"),
      transition = $.mobile._maybeDegradeTransition( o.carouseltransition ),
      complete = function (li, clear) {
        var removeActive = clear ? "ui-carousel-active" : "";
        // don't like
        setTimeout(function(){
          li.off( self._transitionEndEvents, complete )
            .removeClass( o.carouseltransition + " in out " +  removeActive);
        },200);
      }

    // active elements needs to transition out
    activeElement
      .addClass(transition + " out")
      .on( self._transitionEndEvents, complete(activeElement, true) );

    // element clicked contains a reference to the element
    // that should be the new active element
    e.target.reference
      .addClass(transition + " in ui-carousel-active")
      .on( self._transitionEndEvents, complete(e.target.reference) );

}
```

So my idea was that both the element to be de-activated as well as the element having to be activated share the same `complete` function with the difference of `ui-carousel-active` being removed.

My problem is the `transitionEnd` event is triggered immediately, so the transition classes (`transition` being for example `slide`) and `in/out` are removed immediately, which causes no transition to appear on the screen.

Adding the `setTimeout` solves this, but then I would not need to listen for `transitionEnd`.

**Question:**
Why is my `transitionEnd` trigger firing immediately and not once the transition ends? Is there a better way to do this?

Thanks!

**EDIT**:
Transitions in jQuery Mobile are CSS3 transitions, which are triggered by adding/removing classes to an element. For example:

```
/* slide up */
.slideup.out {
-webkit-animation-name: fadeout;
-webkit-animation-duration: 100ms;
-moz-animation-name: fadeout;
-moz-animation-duration: 100ms;
animation-name: fadeout;
animation-duration: 100ms;
}
.slideup.in {
-webkit-transform: translateY(0);
-webkit-animation-name: slideinfrombottom;
-webkit-animation-duration: 250ms;
-moz-transform: translateY(0);
-moz-animation-name: slideinfrombottom;
-moz-animation-duration: 250ms;
transform: translateY(0);
animation-name: slideinfrombottom;
animation-duration: 250ms;
}
.slideup.in.reverse {
-webkit-animation-name: fadein;
-webkit-animation-duration: 150ms;
-moz-animation-name: fadein;
-moz-animation-duration: 150ms;
animation-name: fadein;
animation-duration: 150ms;
}
.slideup.out.reverse {
-webkit-transform: translateY(100%);
-webkit-animation-name: slideouttobottom;
-webkit-animation-duration: 200ms;
-moz-transform: translateY(100%);
-moz-animation-name: slideouttobottom;
-moz-animation-duration: 200ms;
transform: translateY(100%);
animation-name: slideouttobottom;
animation-duration: 200ms;
}
```

So adding the classes `slideup in` will trigger a slideup transition. Adding classes `slideup in reverse` will reverse it, and so on.

Comment: transitionEnd is an event that works with CSS transitions, not JS animations ?

Comment: jQuery mobile is using CSS transitions. Hold up, I post a little of the CSS.

Comment: is it possible to reproduce this on fiddle?

Comment: @Omar: hello again. Hold up. I will try to upload

Comment: @Omar: sorry, not working. I need JQM 1.4pre...

Comment: Are you working on JQM 1.4 code? Any spoilers? ;) as far as I know, collapsible refresh will be fixed in 1.4.

Comment: @Omar: I usually work with latest JQM (now [1.4pre](http://code.jquery.com/mobile/latest/jquery.mobile.js)). I like it a lot although it breaks pretty much everything I did, because I'm kind of overwriting all the CSS most of the time.

Comment: Interesting..If I want to contribute to jQM by fixing some widgets (e.g. collapsible refresh method), what should I do? from where I should start?

Comment: @Omar: in a nutshell: do like this: fork JQM repository on Github, clone to your local machine, create a new branch for your fixes, make your fixes, add tests on Qunit for any new things or functionalities your are adding, commit and push, on your Github fork create a pull-request to JQM. Details [here](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md)

Comment: I'm working now on linking external multi-page with another one, and activating jQM transition between them. I managed to load pages using .load(), but stuck at transition effect from active page to first page in the new file. Are you into this?

Comment: @Omar: external plugin or hacking inside JQM? Your problem will be that JQM `loadPage` or any of the following functions will only take the first `<div data-role="page">` and ditch the rest. In general tough, I don't think it's such a good idea. I did it myself when doing [multiview](https://github.com/frequent/multiview) for JQM 1.1/2, but this was a pain to get working. So... sorry, can't really help.

Comment: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32591/room-for-omar-and-frequent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mh...

```
// active elements needs to transition out
activeElement
  .addClass(transition + " out")
  .on( self._transitionEndEvents, complete(activeElement, true) );

// element clicked contains a reference to the element
// that should be the new active element
e.target.reference
  .addClass(transition + " in ui-carousel-active DUMB")
  .on( self._transitionEndEvents, complete(e.target.reference) );
```

The problem is adding a class of "transition" (e.g. `slide`) and `in` will trigger a transition BEFORE setting the listener for it. That's why it did not work.

Simply changing order to first listening and then triggering:

```
// active elements needs to transition out
activeElement
  .on( self._transitionEndEvents, complete(activeElement, true) )
  .addClass(transition + " out");


// element clicked contains a reference to the element
// that should be the new active element
e.target.reference
  .on( self._transitionEndEvents, complete(e.target.reference) )
  .addClass(transition + " in ui-carousel-active");
```

fixes it and I can remove the `setTimeout` call.